# How do I know which is value is expected without running the code?

Tags: r, statistics, theory

Can you please help. I have to know which value is expected. It would be great if you can justify your answer so that I can better understand it.

```
v <- rep(TA, 12) 

  for(i in 1:12) { 
    x2 <- runif(200)
    x3 <- runif(200) 
    y <- rnorm(-2.7 + 0.9 * x2 -1.8 * x3, sqrt(1.6))
    model <- lm(y ~ x2 + x3)
    v[i] = coef(model)[1]
  }
  mean_v = mean(v)
```

Comment: This smacks a bit of a "will someone do my homework for me?" type question. What is it that you specifically need help to understand? Do you know what `lm` and `coef` do? The clue is that `coef(model)[1]` gives you the intercept of the model (i.e. the expected value of y when x2 and x3 are 0). If you can figure this out, you have your answer.

Comment: Sry for my bad formulation it's for exam preparation. I know that x2, x3 are vectors with 200 values uniform distributed. With rnorm( mean, sd) I get a vector which is normal distribution. My problem is that I thought that I have to calculate the mean of x2 and x3 which is propably 0,5 and then put it in the formula. so that ```y <- rnorm(-3,15, sqrt(1,6))````. And the intercept which I'm looking for is then my mean = -3,15. But with your help -2,7 should be the answer. Am I right?

Comment: Why can't you run the code? We can't run your code because we don't have `TA`

Comment: Is TA not only for initialization. TA will be overwritten by the intercepts. I didn't 
initialized TA and got for mean(v) approximately 1,2 +/- 0,3. But the reason I asked is that I can't explain me how to get this value.

Comment: @Player are you sure there isn't an error in your code? The first argument to `rnorm` should be the size of sample you want to draw. It seems like you are missing a `200` before the expression calculating the mean of y

Comment: @Allan Cameron thank you very much. Now the output makes sense :D